# How to make a quick db select of the range of latitude and longitude in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

There are some table:

```python
class Place(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='places_user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='place-images')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Please tell me how to make a quick select of a certain range of latitudes and longitudes.

For example, there are about 100,000 records. I need to choose a records in which the longitude is 101.25..117.39 and latitude is 223.46..232.55.

I think to use a postgres as a database.

**In the result i think use Postgis + GeoDjango.** 
Details: [GeoDjango blog page](http://andilabs.github.io/django/devops/tools/postgres/postgis/2015/01/31/postgis-geodjango-english.html).

Comment: If you are doing a lot of serious work with location data consider Postgis + GeoDjango.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#range) query:

```
Place.objects.filter(
    longitude__range=(101.25, 117.39),
    latitude__range=(223.46, 232.55),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, there are ways to speed up [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#range)?

Comment: Well, the SQL-equivalent for `range` is `SELECT ... WHERE ... BETWEEN ...` so I don't think speed optimizations using Raw SQL are possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the result i think use Postgis + GeoDjango. Details: [GeoDjango blog page](http://andilabs.github.io/django/devops/tools/postgres/postgis/2015/01/31/postgis-geodjango-english.html).